# GLIBCXX_3.4.26 not found in Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, glibc, debian-buster

Is there any way to install GLIBCXX_3.4.26 in Linux Debian 10?

---

Here is the output of following command: **strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX**

GLIBCXX_3.4

GLIBCXX_3.4.1

...

GLIBCXX_3.4.25

GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH

---

In the output, upto GLIBCXX_3.4.25 is there, but GLIBCXX_3.4.26 is missing.